# How to add category description isnide hook?

Tags: wordpress, hook, categories, advanced-custom-fields, blogs

how can I insert a category description inside the hook, or at least an adc field assigned to this category?  echo category_description does not work.
I didn't work very much with hooks, unfortunately I couldn't find additional information, so I'm turning to professionals

```
<?php
        $terms = get_terms(array(

            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent' => 0
        ));
        foreach ($terms as $val) {
            $image = get_field('obrazek', 'kategoria_' . $val->term_id);

            echo '<div    id="' . $val->slug . '">';
            echo '<a name="' . $val->slug . '"></a>';
            echo '<h2 class="cat-name ">' . $val->name . '</h2>';
            
            $subterm = get_terms(
                array(

                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    'parent' => $val->term_id
                )
            );
```